# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have the following error in building spring boot application.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) on project Krawl: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run failed: A required class was missing while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.14/commons-compress-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.6/maven-archiver-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.7/maven-shared-utils-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M5/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.8.1/plexus-archiver-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.3.2/plexus-io-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/2.2/maven-shade-plugin-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/asm/asm-commons/3.3.1/asm-commons-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/org/vafer/jdependency/0.7/jdependency-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/Raghu%20DV/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10559
I tried with `-U` on `spring-boot:run` as mentioned in above link still getting the same exception.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.krawl</groupId>
    <artifactId>Krawl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Krawl</name>
    <description>Krawl Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.13</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I deleted the entire project and imported everything new, still the exception occurs. This is only happening in Eclipse (I am using Eclipse Oxygen). I am able to run `mvn spring-boot:run` on a linux machine with no issues.

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT version of spring boot? There are already milestone releases out ..?

Comment: spring boot `2.0.0.M7` worked fine. Thanks. I still couldn't figure out what was the error?

Comment: i am using the spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE Still facing the same issue all things  are  same for me in my  application. I have initialized from  spring.io site and download the zip after extracting zip imported that  in  my eclipse oxygen. try to run the application using spring-boot:run

Comment: as i  check with  spring -boot 1.5.0-RELEASE its working fine